# Undefined control sequence - \psset

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to build [the image on this page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg):

[image]

When I execute "tex Cartesian_coordinates_2D.tex" eventually I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\psaxes@vii ... \pst@dimd {#6}\pst@dima =\dimexpr
                                              \pst@dima -\pst@dimg \rela...
<to be read again>
               \psset
l.8 \psset
      {linewidth=.4pt}
?
```

This is the first time I've used Tex so I don't know what to do.

This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
Windows 7 Pro x64

[edit]

Alternately, when I try to run the script in Texworks I get the following error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: xkeyval loaded before \documentclass.
See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.62 ...yval loaded before \protect\documentclass}
                                              %
?
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What's the file you're trying to compile (ideally in the form of a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Are you sure you are/want to be running `tex` rather than `pdflatex`?

Comment: @DaiBowen It is `pstricks` source, so pdfTeX is not going to work, and it is certainly not a LaTeX document.

Comment: @cfr Ah I see, I'd followed the link to the image but missed that there was tex code beneath the image.

Comment: You can make it work with `pdflatex` if you also load `auto-pst-pdf`  (to be loaded *after* `pstricks`) and use the switch `--enable-write18` (under MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: I want to create a SVG file using the script, not PDF, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Just added an error I get in TexWorks too.

Comment: @posfan12 The instructions tell you how to convert to SVG. To compile with LaTeX, you have to add the `document` environment and `\documentclass` etc. as in Werner's answer. TeXWorks is probably trying to use `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compile this with either `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf` or `xelatex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=0.29cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-15.3,-15.3)(17.4,15.3)

  % Axes
  \psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5]{<->}(0,0)(-14.5,-14.5)(14.5,14.5)
  \psset{linewidth=.4pt}
  \psaxes[Dx=1,Dy=1,labels=none,ticksize=1.5pt](0,0)(-13,-13)(13,13)
  \uput{10pt}[0](0,14){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape y-axis}}
  \uput{10pt}[70](14,0){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape x-axis}}

  % Origin
  \pnode(0,0){O}
  \uput{35pt}[310](0,0){\rnode{Ot}{\psscalebox{1.1}{
          \vbox{\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr$(0,0)$\cr\itshape origin\cr}}}}}
  \nccurve[angleA=315,angleB=145,arrowsize=4pt,
          nodesepA=2pt,nodesepB=-3pt,linecolor=gray]{<-}{O}{Ot}

  % Point
  \psdots[dotstyle=*,dotscale=1.2](3,5)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=.8pt](3,0)(3,5)(0,5)
  \uput{2.5pt}[53](3,5){\psscalebox{1.1}{$P(3,5)$}}

  % Quadrants
  \uput{3cm}[45](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bfseries I}}
  \uput{3cm}[135](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bfseries II}}
  \uput{3cm}[225](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bfseries III}}
  \uput{3cm}[315](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bfseries IV}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `@Werner: Or load `auto-pst-pdf` (see my comment above).

Comment: Can you tell me how to compile it? This is the first time I've used Tex or Texworks.

Comment: I get the same error with Werner's code, if I wasn't being clear.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. @posfan12: that's odd. I haven't tested the LaTeX code yet. I've fixed the original to work with `tex`, though.

Comment: @posfan12 I do get Werner's output, but Okular doesn't display the intermediate files correctly.

Comment: Werner's code worked when I used latex instead of tex.

Answer (score 7):

This code, slightly simplified from Werner's, compiles with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}
\newcounter{quadrant}

\begin{document}

\psset{linewidth=1pt, linejoin=1, arrowsize=8pt,unit=0.29cm}
\begin{pspicture}%
\setcounter{quadrant}{0}
  % Axes
  \psaxes[Dx=5, Dy=5, subticks=5, subticksize=0.5, labelsep=10pt, label]{<->}(0,0)(-14.5,-14.5)(14.5,14.5)[\itshape x-axis, 90][\itshape y-axis, -10]
  \psset{linewidth=.4pt}

  % Origin
  \pnode(0,0){O}
  \uput{35pt}[310](O){\rnode{Ot}{\begin{tabular}{c}
         $(0,0)$\\[-0.7ex]\itshape origin\end{tabular}}}
  \nccurve[angleA=315,angleB=145,arrowsize=4pt,
          nodesepA=2pt,nodesepB=-3pt,linecolor=gray]{<-}{O}{Ot}

  % Point
  \dotnode[dotstyle=*,dotscale=1.2](3,5){P}
 \psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=.8pt](3,0)(3,5)(0,5)
  \uput{2.5pt}[53](3,5){\psscalebox{1.1}{$P(3,5)$}}

  % Quadrants
    \multido{\I=45+90}{4}{\stepcounter{quadrant}\nput[labelsep=3cm]{\I}{O}{\psscalebox{1.6}\expandafter\textbf{\Roman{quadrant}}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The issue is, I think, that `pst-plot.tex` has been updated to rely on `\dimexpr`. This works in a `pspicture` in LaTeX, but not with plain TeX. To compile with plain TeX, you need to substitute `pst-plot97` for `pst-plot`.

```
% original source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg
% licence: CC Attribution-Share Alike Unported 3.0: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en
\input pst-eps\input pst-plot97\input pst-node
\TeXtoEPS
\psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=0.29cm}
\pspicture*(-15.3,-15.3)(17.4,15.3)

% Axes
\psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5]{<->}(0,0)(-14.5,-14.5)(14.5,14.5)
\psset{linewidth=.4pt}
\psaxes[Dx=1,Dy=1,labels=none,ticksize=1.5pt](0,0)(-13,-13)(13,13)
\uput{10pt}[0](0,14){\psscalebox{1.25}{\it y-axis}}
\uput{10pt}[70](14,0){\psscalebox{1.25}{\it x-axis}}

% Origin
\pnode(0,0){O}
\uput{35pt}[310](0,0){\rnode{Ot}{\psscalebox{1.1}{
        \vbox{\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr$(0,0)$\cr\it origin\cr}}}}}
\nccurve[angleA=315,angleB=145,arrowsize=4pt,
        nodesepA=2pt,nodesepB=-3pt,linecolor=gray]{<-}{O}{Ot}

% Point
\psdots[dotstyle=*,dotscale=1.2](3,5)
\psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=.8pt](3,0)(3,5)(0,5)
\uput{2.5pt}[53](3,5){\psscalebox{1.1}{$P(3,5)$}}


% Quadrants
\uput{3cm}[45](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bf I}}
\uput{3cm}[135](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bf II}}
\uput{3cm}[225](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bf III}}
\uput{3cm}[315](0,0){\psscalebox{1.6}{\bf IV}}

\endpspicture
\endTeXtoEPS
\nopagenumbers
\end
```

I tried compiling using the instructions on the linked page, but I have no idea what `skconvert` is or where to get it. In any case, it seems a very circuitous way of going about it. Instead, I used [Werner's instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341135/) to convert the DVI to PS and then PDF:

```bash
tex Cartesian_coordinates_2D.tex
dvips Cartesian_coordinates_2D.dvi
ps2pdf Cartesian_coordinates_2D.ps
```

[image: PDF result]

To convert the PDF to SVG, I used

```bash
pdf2svg Cartesian_coordinates_2D.pdf  Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg
```

which produced a result which displayed correctly in Inkscape.

Comment: Did you crop the image? The original Wikimedia commands do some automatic cropping and such, I think.

Comment: @posfan12 No, I didn't bother. I would probably use `standalone` or something to crop. I can't use the Wikimedia commands without `skconvert` and I don't have that.

Comment: simply use `etex`. No need to use the original `tex` program

Comment: @Herbert I just meant to show how the original instructions were intended to work. But I didn't actually realise that `tex` is not now `etex` by default - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of useful contents, your diagram can be simplified as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}

\psset{unit=2mm,arrowscale=1.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-15,-15)(17,17)
  \psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5,tickwidth=.8pt,ticksize=4pt -4pt,subticks=5,subtickwidth=.4pt,subticksize=.4]{<->}(0,0)(-15,-15)(15,15)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pstGeonode[PointName={P{(3,5)},O},PointNameSep={18pt,10pt},PosAngle={0,-45}](3,5){P}(0,0){O}
  \psCoordinates[showpoints=false,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](P)
  \foreach \i/\j in {45/I,135/II,225/III,315/IV}{\uput{11}[\i](0,0){\bfseries\j}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]