# Cropping a pstricks page/image

Tags: pstricks, standalone, crop

How do I go about cropping an image to specific x and y dimensions? I've tried using standalone and the crop parameter, but the result is always a full page.

Here's the code I am using right now:

```
\documentclass[class=article,crop=true]{standalone}
%,pstricks=true
\usepackage{nopageno,pst-plot,graphicx}
%\def\pshlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
%\def\psvlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
  \pstVerb{gsave 1 0 0 setrgbcolor clippath fill grestore}
  \begin{pspicture}(-160,-160)(160,160)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape a}}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape b}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, adding the pstricks=true parameter causes my plot to disappear, as if it were removed from the page.

Thanks.

[edit]

Here's my latest code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\def\pshlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
\def\psvlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,bgcolor=red,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
  \begin{pspicture}(-160,-160)(160,160)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape\rotatebox{180}{a}}}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape\rotatebox{180}{b}}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It works!

Comment: Why do you have `class=article`?

Comment: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf Somewhere in the docs that was suggested. What other options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

- `pstricks` option only to capture the `pspicture` environment.
- `preview` option to activate `preview` package used internally in `standalone` class. It is also used to avoid getting known errors.
- `margin` option to specify the margin. Format `margin={left bottom right top}` but if you want to make all spaces are equal, use `margin=<dimen>`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin={1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp,linewidth=2pt}
\pstVerb{gsave 1 0 0 setrgbcolor clippath fill grestore}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-160,-160)(160,160)
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape a}}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape b}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The blue frame is intentionally added when converting the PDF to PNG to show the bounding box. The MWE above does not produce this blue frame for sure!

Comment: I want to capture only the region (-160,-160)(160,160). I don't want any margin in addition to that. Is that possible?

Comment: What are you using to compile it? I get an error with latex. Package ifplatform Warning:
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
! Extra \fi.
l.63 \fi

?

Comment: It is almost working now. I updated my first post with my latest code. It fails when it reaches the two lines where "rotatebox" appear.

Comment: Good catch. That did the trick!

Comment: BTW, can you tell me how to rotate the 'a' and 'b' labels also? Thank you.

Comment: @posfan12: `\rotatebox{180}{a}` instead of `a` should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the `article` option gor the `standalone` document class. Further, if you want to crop the image to a specific size, given as an argument to the `pspicture` environment, use the `pspicture*` environment: as you can see, the letter `b` which goes outside the frame of `(-160,-160)×(160,160)` is partially cropped.

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}
%\def\pshlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
%\def\psvlabel#1{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
  \pstVerb{gsave 1 0 0 setrgbcolor clippath fill grestore}
  \begin{pspicture*}(-160,-160)(160,160)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape a}}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape b}}
  \end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Don't forget  to compile with `pdflatex --enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `pdflatex -shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, don't load `auto-pst-ˆdf` and compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Isn't it meant to be red? I used your other answer for my version, though `*` seems easier.

Comment: Do you know why adding `pstricks` makes it all go haywire?

Comment: @cfr: No idea. Actually I never used it as option, and your comment made me test it. Same problem.  Note the documentation  doesn't explicitly mention such an option: it's only  in  the .cls coe (viz `newif\ifsa@pstricks`). Wouldn't it be the default?

Comment: It is in my documentation for `standalone`. For example, page 11 right after `tikz`, it lists `pstricks`. `This option declares that the content contains of one or more pspicture or
pspicture* environments. This sets multi=pspicture,varwidth=false and
loads the pstricks package. Because pspicture* uses pspicture internally it
is also supported. Other environments which use it as well should also be sup-
ported, but might also declared explicitly using \standaloneenv{〈environment
name〉, ...}.`

Comment: Found it! Don't how I managed to not see it. Feeling stupid…

Comment: I get the following error: Package ifplatform Warning:
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (C:\Users\Blah\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
! Extra \fi.
l.63 \fi

Comment: @postfan12:  Under MiKTeX, add the `--enable-write18` switch to pdflatex. This has to be done in your TeX editor settings (details depend on the editor).

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

[image: cropped pstricks image]

Compile the following with `pdflatex --shell-escape`:

```
% based a bit on Bernard's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341143/
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\psset{linecolor=black,bgcolor=red,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
\begin{pspicture}(-160,-160)(160,160)
  % Axes
  \psset{linewidth=2pt}
  \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
  \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape a}}
  \uput{0pt}[90](0,-160){{\large\itshape b}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I want. However, the command adds '-autopp' to the end of my ps file name. This is messing up my workflow, since I later convert the ps file to SVG. How do I get rid of this string?

Comment: Also, the PDF output looks like this, which is not quite right: http://i.imgur.com/Rjk6rIY.png

Comment: Well, it will have to add something. Most likely you can change the suffix if you look in `auto-pst-pdf`'s documentation. But you can't have `\jobname.pdf` because that's already in use. So it is renaming the picture so the PDF can then be included.

Answer (score 0):

without standalone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=320pt,paperheight=330pt,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno,pst-plot,graphicx}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-160,-170)(160,160)
    \psframe*[linecolor=red](-160,-170)(160,160)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 
    4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){{\large\itshape a}}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape b}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```